# Fourier Transform Filter

Tags: fft, matlab

In the below image i have computed the Fourier Transform of an image. Now i want to apply ideal high pass filter on same image using DO=50.Code of Fourier Transform is mentioned with in Image.[image]

Comment: if you have signal process toolbox, then you can use fdatool for designing filter and later on, you can use the filter coefficients in filter command.

Comment: I don't want to use the Tool Box. I want to do it through code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what ideal high pass filter. So, I assumed that HPF is a circle-shaped filter.
This is my code.

```
lena = im2double(rgb2gray(imread('lena.bmp')));
D0 = 50;
lpf = zeros(size(lena));
base_x = linspace(-size(lena,1)/2,size(lena,1)/2,size(lena,1));
base_y = linspace(-size(lena,2)/2,size(lena,2)/2,size(lena,2));
[x,y] = meshgrid(base_x, base_y);
lpf(x.^2+y.^2<D0^2) = 1;
hpf = 1-lpf;

LENA = fftshift(fft2(lena));
RESULT = LENA.*hpf;
result = abs(ifft2(RESULT));
figure, imshow(result,[])
```

First, I make HPF using 1-LPF. (LPF' shape is circle.)
And pixel-wise multiply image by HPF.
Finally, ifft IMAGE.

When you run the above code, you can obtain this result.

[image: original image] 
Original Image
[image: HPF image] HPF Image
[image: result image] Result Image

Comment: why don't you `fftshift` back after HPF?

Comment: Oh! I've forgotten applying fftshift!
`result = ifft2(ifftshift(RESULT)); ` is more correct answer. Thanks!